# css buttons hover effect is not working

Tags: javascript, css, button, hover, web

This is my CSS code:

```
body #slider #btn_edit{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   right:10px;
   top:8px;
   color: inherit;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: none;
}

body #slider #btn_edit :hover {
   color: red;
}
```

And this is my JavaScript code where I create the button:

```
var efb = document.createElement("button");
efb.id = 'btn_edit';
efb.innerHTML = 'EDIT';
document.getElementById("slider").insertBefore(efb, 
document.getElementById("pages").nextSibling);
```

If I hover over the button nothing happens. The JavaScript code works just fine but I'm having a problem with the css part; it does not turn red.

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: **Syntax error:** remove the space between the `id` selector and *pseudo-class*, e.g: `body #slider #btn_edit:hover`

Comment: It seems that the button is not inside the `slider` element, but before, so the css selector should be something like `body #btn_edit:hover`

Answer (score 2):

The :hover selector should be attached to your element without the white space.

```
body #slider #btn_edit:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w3ht37p1/

Comment: I have tried that myself but it still is not working

Comment: I've included the jsfiddle which shows as working... perhaps you've not given correct information? Or are you looking to change background-color instead of color which changes text? You might also have other CSS overriding in the browser... You can check this in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Remove space between "#btn_edit :hover". Check snippet code below. Hope it helps
. Also make sure your html looks like mine or the css can target through parents to child(cascading)

```css
body #slider #btn_edit{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   right:10px;
   top:8px;
   color: inherit;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: none;
}

body #slider #btn_edit:hover {/**Removed space between "#btn_edit :hover" **/
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
<!--divs, span ...-->
  <!--divs, span ...-->
  <button id="btn_edit">
    button
  </button>
  <!--divs, span ...-->
    <!--divs, span ...-->
</div>
```